# How to make div/section flexible when the browser size/screen resolution is change?

Tags: css, webkit

The GUI of my system works well with 1366 X 768. When it is displayed in a different resolution, i need to scroll side by side, wherein it should not. Also, the div and section becomes disorted when i tried to press `ctr+-` in chrome.

```
<header>
    <h1><font color = "#666" face="Arial Black" size="5%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Isplika:</font> A Web-based IDE for C++ Source Content for Programming  Beginners
    <span id = "strength" > Our Stength, Our God Ü </span>
    </h1>
</header> 

<div id = "wrapper">

    <section id = "board">

        <section id = "board_c">
            <div id = "board_ln"> </div>
            <div id = "board_code_w">
                <div id = "tags_c" class = "tags">C++ Code</div>
                <div id = "board_code" contenteditable = "true" ></div>
                <div id = "board_code_dup" contenteditable = "false"></div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id = "board_mb">   
        </section>

        <section id = "board_code_info">

           Row: 
           <section id = "row" class="tab_space_right">
            1
           </section> 

           Col:
           <section id = "col" class="tab_space_right">
             2
           </section>

           Number of Lines:
           <section id = "numLines" class="tab_space_right">
             3  
           </section>

        </section>
    </section>

    <section id = "interpreter">
        <div id = "tags_int" class = "tags">Result</div>
        <section id = "interpreter_c">
        </section>
        <section id = "interpreter_input">
        <input id = "inputF" type = "text" />
        </section>
        <div id = "inputB" class="buttons">
        INPUT
        </div>
    </section>    

    <section id = "identifier">

            <div id = "tags_iden" class = "tags">Variables</div>

            <section id = "identifier_type">

            </section>

            <section id = "identifier_name" >

            </section>

            <section id = "identifier_value">

            </section>
    </section>    

    <section id = "controls">
        <div id = "run" class = "buttons" >RUN</div>
        <div id = "stop" class = "buttons" >STOP</div>
        <div id = "next" class = "buttons" >NEXT</div>
        <div id = "support" class = "buttons" >SUPPORT</div>
    </section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

`#board` should be resizable but `#interpreter` and `#identifier` should be static

Comment: You need to create a responsive design, It will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve it easily with javascript(jquery).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function resizeBoard(){
        $('#board').css(width, ($(window).width() - $(#interpreter).width());
    }
    resizeBoard();

    $(window).resize(function() {
         resizeBoard();  
    });
});
```

I would also put it in a resize function so it will be executet everytime you resize your screen.

greetings Timotheus

Answer (score 1):

You can make your webpage more flexible by using percentages instead of pixels when applying margin/padding. For example instead of doing `margin: <value>px;` use `margin: <value>%;`

Comment: using % will make them all resizable isn't it? i want #interpreter and #identifier to be static

Comment: Do you mean that they must have a fixed width and height? Then you can just specify the width/height of those elements in the code but you can make the rest resizable. Another option is if you want them to be at least half the width of the screen to make them 50%. If that's not what you want please leave a small fiddle.